# A directive that Return a promise when an image has been fully rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is this at all possible?   I would love a directive like ng-src that would have an option for a callback expression in the directive signature?   I literally have zero ideas on how this would work; moreover hardly have a use case but I'm curious if it is at all possible?

Comment: Like this: `<img ng-src="url" callback="loaded()">`?

Comment: The call back would have after the image has been fully painted to the page.  But yeah

Comment: Onload completed?  Is that the same?   Say we have a slow connection I want to make sure that the image is completely loaded and painted to the document

Comment: Well `The load event is fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading.`. So it should be what you want. You need to test it with big images in different browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create directive to handle image `onload` event:

```
app.directive('onLoad', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            onLoad: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('load', function(e) {
                scope.onLoad({$event: e});
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and then use it this way:

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}" on-load="loaded()">
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/HdolKL84dsCuoFHur0ZX?p=info